# Move Elements and restrict by child

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to move elements within child records only.  When I run my xsl against one Employee the results are as desired. However running xsl against two or more employees results are not as desired.

xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:xx="urn:com.me/a">
<xx:PayGroup>
<xx:Header>
<xx:recs>2</xx:recs>
</xx:Header>
<xx:Employee>
<xx:Summary>
<xx:Employee_ID>0000000aa</xx:Employee_ID>
</xx:Summary>
<xx:Position>
<xx:Position_ID xx:PriorValue="">Pos1</xx:Position_ID>
<xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="">bad1</xx:Organization_One>
<xx:Organization_Three xx:PriorValue="">good1</xx:Organization_Three>
</xx:Position>
<xx:Additional_Information>
<xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">a001</xx:Payroll_ID>
<xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="a">aa1</xx:Organization_One>
<xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="a">aa2</xx:Organization_Two>
<xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="a">aa3</xx:Organization_Four>
</xx:Additional_Information>
</xx:Employee>
<xx:Employee>
<xx:Summary>
<xx:Employee_ID>0000000bb</xx:Employee_ID>
</xx:Summary>
<xx:Position>
<xx:Position_ID xx:PriorValue="">Pos2</xx:Position_ID>
<xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="">bad2</xx:Organization_One>
<xx:Organization_Three xx:PriorValue="">good2</xx:Organization_Three>
</xx:Position>
<xx:Additional_Information>
<xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">b001</xx:Payroll_ID>
<xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="b">bb1</xx:Organization_One>
<xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="b">bb2</xx:Organization_Two>
<xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="b">bb3</xx:Organization_Four>
</xx:Additional_Information>
</xx:Employee>
</xx:PayGroup>
</xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0" xmlns:xx="urn:com.me/a">
<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xx:Employee_ID">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:copy-of      
Select="/xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees/xx:PayGroup/xx:Employee  
/xx:Additional_Information/xx:Payroll_ID"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xx:Position/xx:Organization_One"></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xx:Position/xx:Position_ID">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:copy-of select="//xx:Additional_Information/xx:Organization_One"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="//xx:Additional_Information/xx:Organization_Two"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="//xx:Additional_Information/xx:Organization_Four"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:xx="urn:com.me/a">
    <xx:PayGroup>
    <xx:Header>
    <xx:recs>2</xx:recs>
    </xx:Header>
    <xx:Employee>
    <xx:Summary>
    <xx:Employee_ID>0000000aa</xx:Employee_ID>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">a001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">b001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    </xx:Summary>
    <xx:Position>
    <xx:Position_ID xx:PriorValue="">Pos1</xx:Position_ID>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="a">aa1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="b">bb1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="a">aa2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="b">bb2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="a">aa3</xx:Organization_Four>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="b">bb3</xx:Organization_Four>
    <xx:Organization_Three xx:PriorValue="">good1</xx:Organization_Three>
    </xx:Position>
    <xx:Additional_Information>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">a001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="a">aa1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="a">aa2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="a">aa3</xx:Organization_Four>
    </xx:Additional_Information>
    </xx:Employee>
    <xx:Employee>
    <xx:Summary>
    <xx:Employee_ID>0000000bb</xx:Employee_ID>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">a001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">b001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    </xx:Summary>
    <xx:Position>
    <xx:Position_ID xx:PriorValue="">Pos2</xx:Position_ID>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="a">aa1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="b">bb1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="a">aa2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="b">bb2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="a">aa3</xx:Organization_Four>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="b">bb3</xx:Organization_Four>
    <xx:Organization_Three xx:PriorValue="">good2</xx:Organization_Three>
    </xx:Position>
    <xx:Additional_Information>
    <xx:Payroll_ID xx:PriorValue="">b001</xx:Payroll_ID>
    <xx:Organization_One xx:PriorValue="b">bb1</xx:Organization_One>
    <xx:Organization_Two xx:PriorValue="b">bb2</xx:Organization_Two>
    <xx:Organization_Four xx:PriorValue="b">bb3</xx:Organization_Four>
    </xx:Additional_Information>
    </xx:Employee>
    </xx:PayGroup>
    </xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

For employee 1 I don't want any value that starts with "b" and for employee 2 I don't want any value that starts with "a".

Is there a simple parm that can be added to restrict the application of the templates to employee by employee?

Comment: oops, forgot the xsl

Comment: Please edit the question and add the XML, XSL and Output, instead of the images. This helps others to copy the contents to find the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with expression...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/xx:Payroll_Extract_Employees/xx:PayGroup/xx:Employee/xx:Additional_Information/xx:Payroll_ID"/>
```

By starting the expression with `/` you are searching from the document node, not the current node you are positioned on, so you will end up selecting all `Payroll_ID` nodes in your document.

As you want to restrict it to the `Employee` you are currently processing, you should do this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::xx:Employee/xx:Additional_Information/xx:Payroll_ID"/>
```

Similarly for the `Organization_???` selections

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//xx:Additional_Information/xx:Organization_One"/>
```

This should become this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::xx:Employee/xx:Additional_Information/xx:Organization_One"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your fast response. That did it.

Comment: @Bryant: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.